# Expand and reduce the TreeItem , on the selection of Other TreeItem in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gwt2

I am using GWT ,
I have tree Widget.TreeItems are added at runtime.
example:

```
   1.A
   2.B
```

when i click on A
It looks like

```
    1.A
       1.ab
       2.cd
    2.B
```

When I click on B
It looks like

```
    1.A
       1.ab
       2.ad
    2.B.
       1.bz
       2.by
```

I want is like, when i click on B , all the TreeItem should be reduced.
like:

```
     1.A
     2.B.
       1.bz
       2.by
```

i am confused how to do this.

i am using on SelectionHandler to expand the treeItem.

Can somebody help me to understand and how to do this.
Also the keywords to do this.

Edited : More Information

This A and B are the TreeItems of the same tree and are addded at run time.

```
public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
// the item which is selected send some keyword to server and server returns the child of the treeItem 
}
```

.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over all other top level items collapsing them along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can on the selection handler of B use closeAll() (Tree class method) which will closes all the nodes of the Tree and after use openAll(TreeNode node)(Tree class method) to open B and all the nodes under B.
To access directly to the Tree under your TreeGrid use the method `yourTreeGrid.getTree()`  so it will be for example `yourTreeGrdi.getTree().closall().

Regards
Alain